Prove that K5 doesn't imply K4
I wanted to convince myself that modal logic K5 doesn't imply K4
So $\mathbf{K} + \Diamond A \rightarrow \Box\Diamond A  \not\vdash\Box A \rightarrow\Box\Box A $
I tried this by constructing a model where $\Box A \rightarrow \Box\Box A $ is false and $\Diamond A \rightarrow \Box\Diamond A$ is true
The first bit is easy in a 3 world model with $ w_{1}\vdash A $ and $w_{2}\vdash\neg A$ ($w_{0}$ undecided)
Where $w_0$ sees $w_1$ and $w_1$ sees $w_2$ (that are all relations , so a K frame)
But if I try this $\Diamond A \rightarrow \Box\Diamond A$ is false at $w_{0}$
How can I prove that K5 doesnt imply K4?

I think you might be mixing up intuitionistic and modal semantics... in the latter, every world decides every proposition. Also, you have not specified the accessibility relation for your modal (so I'm not sure on what basis you're concluding things are true or false there). There is a three-world model that works.

As I can understand, we are asked to evaluate the axioms at $w_{0}$ for the case that aproposition $A$ is true at $w_{1}$ and false at $w_{2}$.
Let us recall
System K4:

The axiom $\Box A\to\Box\Box A$ is added to K. This reflects the transitivity of the accessibility relation

$$R(x, y)\text{ and }R(y, z)\implies R(x, z)$$
System K5:

The axiom $\Diamond A \to \Box \Diamond A$ is added to K. This reflects the Euclidean property of the accessibility relation

$$R(x, y)\text{ and }R(x, z)\implies R(y, z)$$
Therefore, to show that $K5\not\vdash K4$, we need to construct a model with an Euclidean but not transitive relation. Consider a model $\mathcal{M}=\langle W, R, V\rangle$, where:

$W = \{w_{0}, w_{1}, w_{2}\}$

$R$ is defined as $R=\{(w_{0},w_{1}),(w_{1},w_{1}),(w_{1},w_{2}),(w_{2},w_{1}),(w_{2},w_{2})\}$


This relation is Euclidean:
$R(w_{1}, w_{1})$ and $R(w_{1}, w_{2})\implies R(w_{1}, w_{2})$ and thus, $R(w_{2}, w_{1})$ by commutativity of conjunction
$R(w_{2}, w_{1})$ and $R(w_{2}, w_{2})\implies R(w_{2}, w_{1})$ and similarly, $R(w_{1}, w_{2})$
However, it is not transitive, because:
$R(w_0, w_1)$ and $R(w_1, w_2)\not\!\!\!\implies R(w_0, w_2)$.
With the given accessibility relation, it should not be difficult to check that K5 holds, but K4 fails.
